# css: image covers container while being vertically centered

Tags: html, css, image, centering

Being quite new to css, I am trying to achieve the following result:

the image in the left container (see screenshot) always fills its container for 100%, while being vertically centered (and overflow should be hidden).
The height of the container (dashed lines) depends on the height of the three stacked rows; this means that the container height cannot be fixed.

[image]
So far, I tried the folowing:

```
<style>
div {height: 100%; max-height: 368px; overflow: hidden;}
img {width: 100%; object-fit: cover; object-position: 0 50%;
</style>

<div >
     <img  src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

However, this does not seem to work. The `object-position`property only works when `object-fit` is set to `none`. Also, `vertical-align: middle;` doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to specify the image width(and probably height) explicitly to make object-fit work.

Comment: That does not seem to help, the object fit does work (it covers the entire container), however the image does not center vertically

Comment: can you make a codesandbox, jsbin or ...?

Comment: Why didn't you show the CSS and HTML?

Comment: This is part of a large website running Magento and Foundation, so I'm not sure how to include all the code that might have influence